# decrypt a smime mail

Tags: windows-7, encryption, private-key

I received a mail using the webfrontend of my mail provider. It includes the smime.p7m file. I can download this file and want to decrypt it. I have the pfx file with the private key. How can I decrypt it in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [p7mViewer](http://www.cryptigo.eu/smime.p7m/) (untested)
- [smime](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html) from OpenSSL package
- Receive mail with any S/MIME capable e-mail client with added in it own certificate

Comment: p7mViewer is not free. The OPenSSL package looked a bit oversized for just decoding some files.